# synchronized block inside infinite loop

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have two threads, say **T1** and **T2**, which act concurrently on the same object **obj**:

```
class T1 extends Thread {
  public void run() {
    while(true) {
      synchronized(obj) {
        while(condition) {
          ...do something...
          obj.wait();
        }
        ...do something else...
        obj.notify();
      }
    }
  }
}


class T2 extends Thread {
  public void run() {
    while(true) {
      synchronized(obj) {
        while(!condition) {
          ...do something...
          obj.wait();
        }
        ...do something else...
        obj.notify();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So, say **T1** acquires lock first, enters the `while(condition)` loop and suspends himself. On the other hand, **T2** is now free to acquire lock: `!condition` is not met so it doesn't enter inner `while` loop, it does something else and then calls `obj.notify()`.
What I'm expecting is: **T1** wakes up, acquires lock and so on, but most of the times what I see is that **T1** is not able to acquire lock and therefore **T2** executes again.

I'm asking you if this behavior is caused by the `while(true)` loop, or what else.

Answer (score 6):

In threading there are no guarantees. One or the other of the threads will hit the synchronized block first and you should never count on either behaviour.

In practice the currently running thread has no "startup" cost so is more likely to hit the synchronized block first.

The key here is to not worry about which thread is doing what when but to focus on reducing contention. Get as much processing as possible out of that synchronized block and evaluate whether you really need to synchronize everything or whether you can synchronize just a small part of the work, or have multiple different objects to lock against.

Comment: Thank you. Don't worry, it is an exercise :)